# Parsing through URL's in CSV file - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, append

I have a CSV file of URL's and I'm attempting to write a code to loop through the URLs and append specific variables them I have in a dictionary. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt this using beautiful soup the program does not separate the URLs or only does the first URL. I understand this is likely a simple issue but I have been unable to resolve this using solutions from similar questions. Below I've attached an excerpt of the code. Thank you for any guidance.

```
csv_data:
'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000017,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000115752312004450,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000115752312002789,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000013,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000029,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800312000008,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800314000046'


content = requests.get(csv_data[1]).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

reports = soup.find('myreports')

master_reports = []

for report in reports.find_all('report')[:-1]:

report_dict = {}
report_dict['name_short'] = report.shortname.text
report_dict['category'] = report.menucategory.text
report_dict['url'] = base_url + report.htmlfilename.text

master_reports.append(report_dict)

print(base_url + report.htmlfilename.text)
print(report.shortname.text)
print(report.menucategory.text)
```

Comment: is your csv data actually a string?

Comment: If you could show an example of the data that would help

Comment: It was originally a list and then I used 'df = pd.DataFrame(list1)' to convert it to a CSV.

Comment: `csv_data[1]` is not defined. Please consider fixing that and make sure your code is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? splitting the url list and looping? If so, you'll have to collect the output for each loop, which isn't coded here.

```
csv_data = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000017,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000115752312004450,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000115752312002789,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000013,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000029,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800312000008,https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800314000046'
csv_url_list = csv_data.split(',')
for url in csv_url_list:
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    reports = soup.find('myreports')

    master_reports = []

    for report in reports.find_all('report')[:-1]:

    report_dict = {}
    report_dict['name_short'] = report.shortname.text
    report_dict['category'] = report.menucategory.text
    report_dict['url'] = base_url + report.htmlfilename.text

    master_reports.append(report_dict)

    print(base_url + report.htmlfilename.text)
    print(report.shortname.text)
    print(report.menucategory.text)
```

Comment: Hi yes, that is what I'm looking to do, I'm just unfamiliar with looping through lists and appending the information of the output in each loop. Any examples you know of that are applicable to my example?

Comment: If you can supply what master reports looks like maybe I can offer some help. It's not clear what the output is for each link you are visiting is intended to be.  A dataframe, list, dictionary, etc?

Comment: It's a list that contains the name, category and the URL in those links.  The format looks like this:                                                                                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/200406/000020040620000035/R1.htm
0001000 - Document - Cover
Cover
Cover
1

Comment: if i navigate to https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000007800313000017, I can't get a result in reports = soup.find('myreports'). so it's not clear still how you want this captured for all links in the list. Can you post what reports is? And what is in reports.find_all('report')?